# Problem with top-left aligning text in tabular using pictures

Tags: tables

I've been trying to make a table with tabular, and I'm having an issue when trying to align text top left in my table. This is what it looks like. 
[image]

I want the right and left text to be top-left aligned, but I dont't know what I should do. I would really appreciate some help. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Materials utilitzats per dur a terme l'experiment.}

    \begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | c | p{5cm} | }
    \hline
    \textbf{Materials} & \textbf{Fotografia} & \textbf{Descripció/Funció} \\ \hline
    Vareta roscada

    &

    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{sample.png}
    \end{minipage}

    & 

      Vareta de metall rígida que suporta les boles de petanca.

    \\ \hline
    Vareta roscada

    &

    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{sample.png}
    \end{minipage}

    & 

      Vareta de metall rígida que suporta les boles de petanca.

    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}

    \caption{Materials utilitzats}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

The images are the ones set with their alignment at the baseline. If you adjust the baseline to the `t`op (thanks to [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)), the remaining already-top-aligned paragraph columns line up as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Materials utilitzats per dur a terme l'experiment.}

  \begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | c | p{5cm} | }
    \hline
    \textbf{Materials} & \textbf{Fotografia} & \textbf{Descripció/Funció} \\ \hline
    Vareta roscada &
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth, height=60mm, valign=t]{example-image-a} & 
    Vareta de metall rígida que suporta les boles de petanca. \\
    \hline
    Vareta roscada &
    \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth, height=60mm, valign=t]{example-image-b} & 
    Vareta de metall rígida que suporta les boles de petanca. \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % <---load also graphicx

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=60mm}
\begin{tabular}{ | *{3}{p{\dimexpr0.333\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-0.66\arrayrulewidth} |} }
    \hline
    \textbf{Materials} & \textbf{Fotografia} & \textbf{Descripció/Funció} \\ \hline
Vareta roscada  
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{sample.png}
        &   Vareta de metall rígida que suporta les boles de petanca.   \\ 
    \hline
Vareta roscada
    &   \includegraphics[valign=t]{sample.png}
        &   Vareta de metall rígida que suporta les boles de petanca.   \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Materials utilitzats}
\label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```